# Jquery slideToggle not staying down

Tags: jquery, navigation, slidetoggle

I am trying to create a sub-nav that will slide down upon clicking on links located in a separate div above the sub-nav. Currently I have the sub-nav hiding properly. However upon clicking on one of the links, the sub-nav will quickly show just for a few seconds then hide itself again. Can someone help me figure out how to get the sub-nav to drop and then stay down upon clicking?

codepen here: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/tkgmx
video of problem: http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=DcvIwdleMFY&feature=youtube_gdata_player

html

```
<div>
        <ul class="top-nav">
            <li class="click"><a href="vision.php">Click here</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">link 2</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">link 3</a></li>
            <span class="arrow-up"></span>
        </ul>
    </div>
<div class="nav-items">
    <div class="drop-container">
        <ul class="sub-nav">
            <li><a href="">nav item 1</a>|</li>
            <li><a href="">nav item 1</a>|</li>
            <li><a href="">nav item 1</a>|</li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</div>
```

css

```
 .top-nav {
li {
 display: inline;
 list-style: none;
padding-left: 10px;
a {
  display: inline-block;
 }
}
.arrow-up {
width: 0; 
height: 0; 
border-left: 10px solid transparent;
border-right: 10px solid transparent;
border-bottom: 10px solid gray;
position: absolute;
top: 50px;
right: 334px;
}
}


.nav-items {
background-color:gray;  
.drop-container {
.sub-nav {
  list-style: none;
  li {
    display: inline;
    a {
      display: inline-block;
      padding-left: 10px;
      padding-right: 10px;
    }
  }
}
}
}
```

js

```
$(document).ready(
function() {
$( ".nav-drop" ).hide();

$( ".click" ).click(function() {
$( ".nav-items" ).slideToggle( "slow" );
});
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You class selectors seems to be missing `.`

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $(".nav-drop").hide();

    $(".click").click(function () {
        $(".nav-items").slideToggle("slow");
        return false
    });
});
```

Also jQuery library seems to be missing the codepen

Demo: [CodePen](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/lodED)

Comment: This works on codepen, but still having issues locally on page load. See added video above.

Answer (score 0):

Change class name
  $( "click" ) to  $( ".click" ) and   $( "nav-items" ) to  $( ".nav-items" )

```
$(document).ready(
function() {
$( ".nav-drop" ).hide();

$( ".click" ).click(function() {
$( ".nav-items" ).slideToggle( "slow" );
});
});
```